# Elegant way to use variable font with MUI

Tags: reactjs, fonts, material-ui

So I'm using MUI v5 and I'm using variable fonts as well.

Currently, my implementation of the theme is quite ugly in my opinion.

```
typography: {
    fontFamily: systemFonts.join(","),
    fontWeightExtraBold: 800,
    h1: {
      fontSize: "clamp(2.625rem, 1.2857rem + 3.5714vw, 4rem)",
      fontWeight: 800,
      lineHeight: 78 / 70,
      "@supports (font-variation-settings: normal)": {
        fontFamily: variableSystemFonts.join(","),
        fontVariationSettings: "'wght' 800"
      }
    },
    h2: {
      fontSize: "clamp(1.5rem, 0.9643rem + 1.4286vw, 2.25rem)",
      fontWeight: 800,
      lineHeight: 44 / 36,
      "@supports (font-variation-settings: normal)": {
        fontFamily: variableSystemFonts.join(","),
        fontVariationSettings: "'wght' 800"
      }
    },
    h3: {
      fontSize: defaultTheme.typography.pxToRem(36),
      lineHeight: 44 / 36,
      letterSpacing: 0,
      "@supports (font-variation-settings: normal)": {
        fontFamily: variableSystemFonts.join(",")
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
```

Basically, I have to specify

```
"@supports (font-variation-settings: normal)": {
  fontFamily: variableSystemFonts.join(",")
}
```

For every single typography variant.

I'm wondering is there a more elegant, cleaner way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put it in a factory function (Not tested yet):

```
const normalVariation = (extraProperties) => ({
  "@supports (font-variation-settings: normal)": {
    fontFamily: variableSystemFonts.join(","),
    ...extraProperties,
  }
})
```

```
typography: {
    fontFamily: systemFonts.join(","),
    fontWeightExtraBold: 800,
    h1: {
      fontSize: "clamp(2.625rem, 1.2857rem + 3.5714vw, 4rem)",
      fontWeight: 800,
      lineHeight: 78 / 70,
      ...normalVariation({
        fontVariationSettings: "'wght' 800",
      })
    },
    h2: {
      fontSize: "clamp(1.5rem, 0.9643rem + 1.4286vw, 2.25rem)",
      fontWeight: 800,
      lineHeight: 44 / 36,
      ...normalVariation({
        fontVariationSettings: "'wght' 800",
      })
    },
    h3: {
      fontSize: defaultTheme.typography.pxToRem(36),
      lineHeight: 44 / 36,
      letterSpacing: 0,
      ...normalVariation(),
    },
    // ...
  }
```